# Debug Swift Mailer in PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6, swiftmailer

Occasionally sending mails fail with the `Mail::send` function of PrestaShop. I use a external mailserver, and the responsible person there told me that no request was received for sending any mails (I find this strange though). So, I made a little logger doing the following:

```
if ( !Mail::send() )
    // logging details here here..
```

The `Mail::send` returns `false` correctly. Now I would like to know the reason. Therefore I would like to log information about the connection in SwiftMailer. Could someone give me any clues how to solve this in a simple manor (not with SwiftMailer plugins, if possible).

Swift Mailer version: 3.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `$die` param to `true` you will cause that script stop and a bad experience for customer while buying or admin while changing order status, etc. You should check the following:

1. Check if email sending fails on specific email template. If true, you could have a problem with template structure, parameters passed, html rendering, etc.
2. Every error inside `Mail::Send` funtion is logged in Prestashop Logs. So you should check it there. You could know every possible error identifyng this kind of code inside function `Mail::Send`: `Tools::dieOrLog(Tools::displayError('Error: invalid SMTP server or SMTP port'), $die);`
3. Specific Swift exceptions are logged with this code: `PrestaShopLogger::addLog('Swift Error: ' . $e->getMessage(), 3, null, 'Swift_Message');` so it should appear in Prestashop Logs too.
4. Anyway, Swift has his own log in class `Swift_Log_DefaultLog`. You can find it at `\tools\swift\Swift\Log\DefaultLog.php`. You could modify `add` or `dump` function to save logs to an specific file or similar.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Set `$die` parameter true to display the error. You will need `_PS_MODE_DEV_` set to `true` to see it.

```php
/**
 * Send Email
 *
 * @param int $id_lang Language ID of the email (to translate the template)
 * @param string $template Template: the name of template not be a var but a string !
 * @param string $subject Subject of the email
 * @param string $template_vars Template variables for the email
 * @param string $to To email
 * @param string $to_name To name
 * @param string $from From email
 * @param string $from_name To email
 * @param array $file_attachment Array with three parameters (content, mime and name). You can use an array of array to attach multiple files
 * @param bool $mode_smtp SMTP mode (deprecated)
 * @param string $template_path Template path
 * @param bool $die Die after error
 * @param string $bcc Bcc recipient
 * @return bool|int Whether sending was successful. If not at all, false, otherwise amount of recipients succeeded.
 */
public static function Send($id_lang, $template, $subject, $template_vars, $to,
    $to_name = null, $from = null, $from_name = null, $file_attachment = null, $mode_smtp = null,
    $template_path = _PS_MAIL_DIR_, $die = false, $id_shop = null, $bcc = null, $reply_to = null)
```

Alternatively you could go to backoffice and menu `Advanced Parameters -> Logs`, type in a Message filter: `error` and search for results. It's not guaranteed it will show you only email errors but it narrows it down a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to tell you the reason for failure of Mail::send() function. There can be multiple reasons for the failure.

There are 12 lines of code in that returns false in the Mail::send() function, each having a different condition. You need to debug the function to find the exact reason.

You can find the Mail::send() function in Mail.php file at /classes/Mail.php

Tip: You can add log with every 'return false;' statement in the function to check which of them is getting executed.